# Angularjs multiple image upload with cropping

Tags: angularjs, crop, image-uploading

I am finding a good Angularjs code that support multiple image upload with cropping facility.

I have searched a lot but either I get a good multiple image upload or I get single image cropping.

Is there anything which supports both?

Comment: Do you want to insert multiple images and crop all of them or crop these images one by one ?

Comment: Either way will do. Actually inserting multiple images and cropping all will be better.

Comment: This question can be put on hold as: _It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._

Answer (score 1):

I had Also same issue in Angular 8 so i made some changes in ngx-image-cropper,
It allows user to upload multiple images as u can see in below image

[image: like this image it allows multiple image selection from your local system]

and crop them by selecting Image 
[image: Image Cropper]

Comment: Hey, how did you achieve multiple image upload and crop by selecting one them?

Comment: @faizan-abdul-haq Here is the github  repository Url you can check here 
 https://github.com/MMtechnolab/Angular-Typescript--2-8-Multiple-Image-Upload-and-Crop-

Answer (score -1):

```
> <div class="multiple-images">
                                <input  type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvents($event)" multiple/>

                                <div>
                                <image-cropper
                                    [imageBase64]="imageBase64"
                                    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
                                    [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
                                    [resizeToWidth]="128"
                                    [roundCropper]="false"
                                    format="png"
                                    outputType="both"
                                    (imageCropped)="imageCrop($event)"
                                    (imageLoaded)="imageLoad()"
                                    (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFail()"
                                    style="max-height: 33vh"
                                    [style.display]="cropReady ? null : 'none'"
                                ></image-cropper>
                                </div>
                                <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(croppedImages)">
                                    <img  [src]="croppedImages[key]"  />
                                </div>
                            </div>
//multiple image upload start
     imageBase64: string = '';
     objectKeys = Object.keys;
     fileName: string;
     cropReady = false;
     croppedImages: any =[];
     imageName: string;
     fileChangeEvents(event: any): void {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (event: any) => {
                        this.imageBase64 = event.target.result;
        };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
                this.imageName = event.target.files[0].name
                console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
  }
  imageCrop(event: ImageCroppedEvent ) {
        this.croppedImages[this.imageName] = event.base64;
}
imageLoad() {
    this.cropReady = true;
  }
  loadImageFail () {
    console.log('Load failed');
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add additional information, don't use the comments. Does this code have any explanation?

Comment: Provide some explanation with your code to tell what your code is doing!